# Как в PHP вызывать метод класса самим же методом?

Tags: классы, php, методы

К примеру, мне надо, чтобы работал такой код:

```
$classO->mtd(2)->mtd(0)->mtd(1)->print();
```

В общем, как построить класс так, чтобы метод "mtd" мог вызывать сам себя?

Comment: а че заминусили-то? Хоть бы писали. Нормальный же вопрос.

Comment: То, что вы описываете — это не «вызвать себя сам», это «[method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)».

Answer (score 6):

Так же, как и в JS:

```
class my_class{
  public function my_method(){
    return $this;
  }
}
```

**EDIT::**
проблема в том, что такое поведение, вроде бы, доступно только с 5.2 версии.

> 5.2.17 
> "xEdelweiss

Comment: Добавлю, что соль приема [цепочка методов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/170019/) в том, чтоб каждый метод объекта возвращает сам объект (*return $this*).

Comment: @knes, как минимум с 5.2.17, только что проверил

Comment: @xEdelweiss мне было лень ставить 5.2. Но раз работает - отл. Ча поправлю.

Comment: о, я вопроса неправильно понял )

Answer (score 2):

```
class my_class{
  public function my_method(){
    $this->my_method(); // вызвать самого себя
  }
}
```

На сколько помню так должно работать :)

Answer (score 1):

Вызывайте рекурсивно, в чем проблема то?

*Добавлено:*
Условно вы передаете переменную и в методе уже проверяете ее тип. Если массив - разбираете его и на каждое значение вызываете тот же метод. Складываете в итоговую переменную и возвращаете обратно.

Comment: Можно подробнее?